# dspace create-administrator fails

Tags: java, dspace

I am working on installing the dspace 6.1 src release.  I am on Suse 12.2.  I have followed the [installation instructions](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace) carefully, followed the ideas in [this post](https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2408?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel), and cleaned-reinstalled-retried the create-administrator script and the user script numerous times yesterday and today.  I always get the same error:

```
dspace@mycomputer:~/dspace_install> bin/dspace create-administrator
Exception: The schema validator returned: Unable to create requested 
service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
org.dspace.core.exception.DatabaseSchemaValidationException: The 
schema validator returned: Unable to create requested service 
[org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.dspace.core.Context.init(Context.java:170)
    at org.dspace.core.Context.<init>(Context.java:126)
    at org.dspace.administer.CreateAdministrator.<init>
(CreateAdministrator.java:101)
    at (org.dspace.administer.CreateAdministrator.main(CreateAdministrator.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:229)
at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:81)
```

I have not found this error anywhere online.  The closest is that posting from 2015 above.  My database did not have default entries in the epersongroup table, so I added the entries suggested the post above (add 'Anonymous' and 'Administrator' groups).  Still I am getting the same error.

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spoke with my colleague, who found the real problem. We installed 2 instances of Dspace on the same server, and he found the setting for the hibernate ehcache (hibernate-ehcache-config.xml) in the [dspace-src]/dspace/config directory. This was referenced in the exception message I posted in my question above. There is a warning in hibernate-ehcache-config.xml that when you have more than one instance of dspace on the same server, you need separate diskStore folders for the hibernate ehcache. I created a separate one for my Dspace instance, then reversed my setting for dspace.hostname in the local.cfg file so it shows the server domain name, and everything works, the server, and create-administrator on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Since the error reports an issue with the database schema, I recommend the following.

Run the following command to see the status of your database schema

```
bin/dspace database info
```

You will see output like the following

```
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version        | Description                                         | Installed on        | State   |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1              | << Flyway Baseline >>                               | 2017-07-25 18:26:49 | Baselin |
| 1.1            | Initial DSpace 1.1 database schema                  | 2017-07-25 18:26:50 | Success |
| 1.2            | Upgrade to DSpace 1.2 schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:50 | Success |
| 1.3            | Upgrade to DSpace 1.3 schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:50 | Success |
| 1.3.9          | Drop constraint for DSpace 1 4 schema               | 2017-07-25 18:26:50 | Success |
| 1.4            | Upgrade to DSpace 1.4 schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:50 | Success |
| 1.5            | Upgrade to DSpace 1.5 schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 1.5.9          | Drop constraint for DSpace 1 6 schema               | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 1.6            | Upgrade to DSpace 1.6 schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 1.7            | Upgrade to DSpace 1.7 schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 1.8            | Upgrade to DSpace 1.8 schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 3.0            | Upgrade to DSpace 3.x schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 4.0            | Upgrade to DSpace 4.x schema                        | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 4.9.2015.10.26 | DS-2818 registry update                             | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 5.0.2014.08.08 | DS-1945 Helpdesk Request a Copy                     | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 5.0.2014.09.25 | DS 1582 Metadata For All Objects drop constraint    | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 5.0.2014.09.26 | DS-1582 Metadata For All Objects                    | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 5.6.2016.08.23 | DS-3097                                             | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 5.7.2017.04.11 | DS-3563 Index metadatavalue resource type id column | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 5.7.2017.05.05 | DS 3431 Add Policies for BasicWorkflow              | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 6.0.2015.03.06 | DS 2701 Dso Uuid Migration                          | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 6.0.2015.03.07 | DS-2701 Hibernate migration                         | 2017-07-25 18:26:51 | Success |
| 6.0.2015.08.31 | DS 2701 Hibernate Workflow Migration                | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.01.03 | DS-3024                                             | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.01.26 | DS 2188 Remove DBMS Browse Tables                   | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.02.25 | DS-3004-slow-searching-as-admin                     | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.04.01 | DS-1955 Increase embargo reason                     | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.04.04 | DS-3086-OAI-Performance-fix                         | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.04.14 | DS-3125-fix-bundle-bitstream-delete-rights          | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.05.10 | DS-3168-fix-requestitem item id column              | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.07.21 | DS-2775                                             | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.07.26 | DS-3277 fix handle assignment                       | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.0.2016.08.23 | DS-3097                                             | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
| 6.1.2017.01.03 | DS 3431 Add Policies for BasicWorkflow              | 2017-07-25 18:26:52 | Success |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

If you see any items without a status of "Success" run the following

```
bin/dspace database repair
```

If you do not see that the entries include release 6.1, run the following command

```
bin/dspace database migrate
```

Hopefully this will resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks very much for this!  I checked my database immediately, and everything was ok.  I found the problem, though, and it is a bug in dspace.  I had written the domain name of the server in the config file: dspace.hostname.  I changed this setting to localhost, reinstalled dspace (without changing the database), and create-administrator worked!

Comment: My explanation above is incorrect.  My colleague found the real problem. See my posted answer...